# requestsとseleniumで取得できるcookieの種類

Tags: python, python3, selenium, cookie, python-requests

requestsの`s.cookies.get_dict()`と`seleniumのdriver.get_cookies()`で取得できるcookieの構造が違うのですが、なぜですか？

このrequestsで取得したセッションキーをseleniumの方に渡したいのですが、どこの値に入れれば良いかわかりません。詳しい方教えて頂けないでしょうか？なぜ同じcookieなのにseleniumだと全然違うのでしょうか？ブラウザで確認できるcookieと同じなのはrequestsの方です。

**requestsで取得したcookie**

```
{'_b': '"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"', '_pinterest_sess': 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy', '_ir': '0'}
```

**seleniumで取得したcookie**

```
{'domain': '.www.pinterest.jp', 'expiry': 253402257600, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'G_ENABLED_IDPS', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'google'}, {'domain': 'www.pinterest.jp', 'expiry': 1570991859, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'sessionFunnelEventLogged', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '1'}, {'domain': 'www.pinterest.jp', 'expiry': 1602052658.221876, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': '_pinterest_sess', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'}, {'domain': 'www.pinterest.jp', 'expiry': 1571035059.221895, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': '_routing_id', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'}, {'domain': 'www.pinterest.jp', 'expiry': 1602398259.221853, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'csrftoken', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz'}, {'domain': 'www.pinterest.jp', 'expiry': 1602052658.221669, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': '_auth', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': '0'}
```

Comment: 詳細なドキュメントにはアクセス出来ませんでしたが、簡単なガイドの方は GitHub のリンクから飛べました。ほんの少しの記述ですが、参考になるかも。[Cookies | Quickstart - Requests 2.22.0 documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)

Comment: ありがとうございます。読んでみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requestsの公式ドキュメントを探したのですが、期間限定(?)なのか限られた時間しかだめなのかアクセスできませんでした。[Pypiレポジトリのrequestsのページ](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)。

[get_dict関数の実装](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/fab1fd10d0b115e635b9ef1364f8444089725000/requests/cookies.py#L307-L312)を見ると、リクエストしたurlに対応したcookieしか返さないみたいですね。
requestsの保存するcookieのデータを見るには以下でできるみたいです。データ形式は違いそうですね。

```
str(s.cookies)
```

[類似した質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091976/python-requests-get-cookies)を見ると以下でseleniumと同じ形式の辞書が作れそうです。

```
[
    {'name': c.name, 'value': c.value, 'domain': c.domain, 'path': c.path}
    for c in session.cookies
]
```

seleniumにクッキーを追加する場合は、[この記事](https://qiita.com/ytyng/items/5e6dad02a6adabc21fed)が参考になりそうです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただなぜdomain が含まれるcookieと含まれないcookieがあるのでしょうか？上記の2つのcookieが同じものには見えず上手く理解できません。

Comment: Valuesというのを使用すればdomain の含まれるcookieを取得できるのでしょうか？

Comment: get_dict()メソッドは、リクエスト先のドメインに対応したcookieの内容しか返さないので、domainの値を返しません。返す値をフィルターしています。value()メソッドはブラウザが保持するcookieを全て返す実装に見えます。

Comment: 取得できる出来たのはリスト形式になった値でした。なのでディクショナリーの値のみという感じでした。

Comment: この値をフィルターされてないcookie値に代入すればセッション保てますでしょうか？どこに入れて良いのかわからないですが、みなさんname valueに入れる感じでやっていると思うのですが、よく分からないです。

Comment: 回答を修正しました。「セッションを保つ」という目的ならcookie以外の値も見ないとできないかもしれません。requestsとseleniumの通信は別セッションです。片方のセッションとして通信したいなら、[httpsのハンドシェイク](https://milestone-of-se.nesuke.com/nw-basic/tls/https-structure/)を理解する必要があります

Comment: やはりセキュリティ的に難しいという事でしょうか？

Comment: 目的によります。「あるユーザーとして投稿したい」というのなら、requestsモジュールだけでログイン→投稿を模したリクエストをすればできます。「通信を改ざんしたい」となればまた違うやり方が必要です。その場合は新しく質問して回答を募ってみてください！

Comment: ユーザは同じでrequestsログイン後の認証でJavaScriptが上手く動作しないため自動化に失敗します。なので一度requestsで保っていたセッションをseleniumに渡してクリックだけseleniumで行いたいのです。